# Python's PRINT is not outputting the last print() word

Tags: python

My code runs perfectly and with the results that I want.  However, the last print ("Anxious: ") is NOT outputting Anxious: but instead only printing out the answer without the title.

I have run this multiple times in IDLE 3.10.1 as well as my Python I online class's own Python program and I get the exact same result.  Absolutely no errors but no title either after the last print statement.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?  I have not had this kind of problem before in my previous code that I ran for my online class.

Thank you!

```
busy = True
hungry = False
tired = True
stressed = False

happy = busy and not stressed
sad = hungry or tired 

print("Happy: " + str(happy)) 
print("Sad: " + str(sad))
print("Confused: "+ str(happy and sad))
print("Bored: " + str(not(happy or sad or busy))) 
print("Anxious: " + str(not happy) and (not sad) and (not stressed))
```

Comment: Double-check your parentheses on the last line.

Comment: You mean `str((not happy) and (not sad) and (not stressed))`

Comment: Is there a newline at the end of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a logic error:

```
busy = True
hungry = False
tired = True
stressed = False

happy = busy and not stressed
sad = hungry or tired 

print("Happy: " + str(happy)) 
print("Sad: " + str(sad))
print("Confused: "+ str(happy and sad))
print("Bored: " + str(not(happy or sad or busy))) 
print("Anxious: " + str(not happy and (not sad) and (not stressed)))
```

This:

```
print("Anxious: " + str(not happy) and (not sad) and (not stressed)))
```

Should be:

```
print("Anxious: " + str(not happy and (not sad) and (not stressed)))
#or
print("Anxious: " + str((not happy) and (not sad) and (not stressed)))
```

Comment: Thank you Eli!  I added an additional ( ) after str and at the very end of the Anxious statement and it finally printed out the word!

Answer (score 0):

The line

`print("Anxious: " + str(not happy) and (not sad) and (not stressed))`

evaluates to

`print("Anxious: False" and False and True)`

Strings always evaluate to `True`, so you are printing the result of `True and False and True` which simply prints `False`.

Answer (score -1):

Its not working because the paranthesis for `str` is not covering the entire operation it is just covering the `not happy` part of the operation, Thus, all you have to do is to add a new paranthesis to it

```py
print("Anxious: " + str((not happy) and (not sad) and (not stressed)))
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the last code you made a mistake. First, you string the word true, and then you use the logical operator And.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer].